# In spunk how to retrieve only first or last event of each row present in inputlookup file?

Tags: splunk, lookup-tables, splunk-query

In splunk I'm running below query:

Considering I've following data present in `20230922_id.csv`

```
id_
123
234
345
456
```

```
index=1234 application_name="app_name_xyz" app_region=apac "Total time to process request" 
| search [| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv 
  | rename id_ as search 
  | format ]
```

This above query turned into below one (which I'm expecting based on splunk guide)

```
index=1234 application_name="app_name_xyz" app_region=apac "Total time to process request" 
| search 123 or 234 or 345 or 456
```

Currently for each of the above row from CSV file there are `3 events`. So the total event count is coming as `12` which is correct.

Is there any way that each of the data from row (which is `123,234,345,456`) should just return 1 event? So that total event becomes only 4.

I've tried some below solutions but it's not working:

```
index=1234 application_name="app_name_xyz" app_region=apac "Total time to process request" 
| search [| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv 
  | rename id_ as search 
  | head 1 
  | format ]
```

Below one is obvious that it will return just 1 event as I'm doing head on the complete query.

```
index=1234 application_name="app_name_xyz" app_region=apac "Total time to process request" 
| search [| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv 
  | rename id_ as search  
  | format ] 
|head 1
```

Could you please let me know if there is any syntax that could solve my above problem?

If there is not a way to get first/last from each matching row, is there any way to get info as below ?

| id_ | count |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 234 | 3 |
| 345 | 4 |
| 456 | 2 |

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by first and last and how that's relevant in the `count` output. If you want a count of events by `id_` then you could use `| stats count by id_`. Can you explain how first and last events would be used?

Comment: I tried with `|stats count by id_` but it doesn't work.
The first and last occurrence is not exactly relevant with count. But just in case this feature is not available then `count` & `id_` entry could provide me how many such entries exist.  Just like we do `select id_ , count(*) ... group by id_` in sql.

Comment: All I'm interested in how many events from what is there in csv are occurred. Irrespective of it occurred `1 or 1+n times`, I'll just consider it as 1 count.

Comment: is the `id_` field in your lookup also in your event data? If so, is it the same field name, or a different one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a lookup table with a field named `id_` that you want to match in your event data (I think you have a field in said data that matches, correct?)

And then you want to only get the first or last match in your data where the field's value matches what is in the lookup table.

If that is a correct understanding of your use case, this will do it:

```
index=1234 application_name="app_name_xyz" app_region=apac "Total time to process request" 
    [| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv ]
| stats max(_time) as _time by id_
```

Comment: Yes, you've understood my query correctly. What is _time here ? We have timestamp field. I tried with that but it's not working. Here you've just put `[| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv ]` which is not working. So I tried playing with `| stats max(_time) as _time by id_` along with query in my OP. But no result.

Comment: here `id_` is part of only lookup csv but not as part of data stored in splunk . So how to take out `_id` as param out of the `| search [| inputlookup 20230922_id.csv | rename id_ as search | format ]` Because adding `| stats max(_time) as _time by id_` at the end of query will not get the `id_` which is part of only lookup csv file

Comment: @AshwinK - what field does `id_` is the lookup table match in your event data? What does the rest of the lookup table look like? What generates the lookup table?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried dedup?

```
| dedup id_
```

This will give you only the latest entry for each id_. Resulting in one result per id_, which if i understood your question correctly is what you are after.

Comment: This doesn't work.